# Selection criteria for coolant media on spaceships

Tags: heat, cooling, ammonia, liquid-cooled

What is the selection criteria for coolant media on spaceships? I have read that ammonia as well as water glycol have been used. These two have very diverse properties.

So what makes both of them suitable (simultaneously) for use as a radiator coolant for space ships such as Apollo etc?

Comment: It would be great to add a few of those diverse properties, perhaps melting point, boiling point, level of toxicity at a minimum.

Answer (score 3):

For inhabited parts of the vehicle, water and water mixtures are preferred because leaks pose less of a threat to the crew.  An even less threatening heat transfer media is air, which is commonly used to cool equipment in the cabin. For external cooling loops, ammonia and Freon have been used because of their superior heat transfer properties and lower freezing points.

[image]
(Source - personal notes)

Acronymology

ARS - **A**tmosphere **R**evitalization **S**ystem

ATCS - **A**ctive **T**hermal **C**ontrol **S**ystem